# How can I bring back `nil`?

Tags: elisp, interactive-development

I've accidentally run the following:

```
(unintern variable)
```

where `variable`'s value was `nil`.

How do I get `nil` back without restarting Emacs?

Comment: +1 for making me chuckle. :-) Not in a condescending way, but in a "I would have totally done that as well" way.

Comment: @Malabarba :) It was truly a humbling realization when I figured out what I had done

Comment: You can delete nil! Did not see that coming.

Comment: @Gambo neither did I :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`(defconst nil ())`

seems to have the right effect; note that `nil` and an empty list are indistinguishable in Emacs Lisp.

I looked at [`lread.c:4034`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/lread.c?a=25e3ff01d472b6514dea61b1c8cbc9ce88b6979a#n4034) to see how `nil` is created in an `obarray`.

Note the comment at [line 3896 in `lread.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/lread.c?a=25e3ff01d472b6514dea61b1c8cbc9ce88b6979a#n3896):

```
/* There are plenty of other symbols which will screw up the Emacs
     session if we unintern them, as well as even more ways to use
     `setq' or `fset' or whatnot to make the Emacs session
     unusable.  Let's not go down this silly road.  --Stef  */
  /* if (EQ (tem, Qnil) || EQ (tem, Qt))
       error ("Attempt to unintern t or nil"); */
```

This explains why Emacs does not protect against `(unintern nil)` and `(unintern t)`.

Comment: Very clever!  I agree with `Stef` on this one, actually :) Down that road lies madness.

Comment: Bleh. I agree with rms over sm here. Uninterning `nil` is a common error that's easy to protect against. Why put a handrail on a staircase when people could jump over it?

Comment: @Gilles I think about this as I think about C: C maintains the philosophy that the programmer knows what he is doing and merely requires a way to express himself.  IMO, we should regard emacs lisp as the assembly language of emacs; higher abstractions (and guards/features) should be added in a language that compiles to elisp. But that is certainly a topic for another medium :)

Comment: `unintern` is not used frequently, really.  Using it on the main `obarray` is pretty much *always* a bad idea (which is why the byte-compiler complains when you fail to pass the second argument, and `C-h f unintern` doesn't tell you that the second arg is actually still optional).

Comment: @Stefan It would seem that's a documentation bug, then :(

Comment: @SeanAllred: if you think so, then I recommend you `M-x report-emacs-bug` pointing out which part of the doc is misleading and/or explaining what it should say (instead).

Comment: @Constantine Can you please fix the link to the specific line in lread.c? As it is linked to the "master" branch, that line reference won't stay constant.. So it would need reference to an absolute commit in this fashion: `http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/buffer.c?a=a2981c90f661e8fa0356ee5bfe00f8565d721de8\#n2156` (remove that backslash before #).

Comment: @KaushalModi: Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out!