# Is there a way to disable the "buffer is read-only" warning?

Tags: echo-area

I don't find this warning particularly helpful and pretty distracting because it hides the current text in the echo area for a brief moment. Is also seems unnecessary, because I will notice anyway that I cannot write in read-only areas. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can disable these messages by setting [`command-error-function`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processing-of-Errors.html#Processing-of-Errors) to a function that ignores `buffer-read-only` signals.

```el
(defun my-command-error-function (data context caller)
  "Ignore the buffer-read-only signal; pass the rest to the default handler."
  (when (not (eq (car data) 'buffer-read-only))
    (command-error-default-function data context caller)))

(setq command-error-function #'my-command-error-function)
```

(Tested using GNU Emacs 24.5.1.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, won't overriding the `command-error-function` value affect all errors, and not just the "buffer read-only" errors? I cannot exactly figure out what all this change will impact from the source code.

Comment: Yes, it would. That's exactly why I have the `(when ...)` form in the code snippet: this way signals we don't care about are passed to the default handler and `buffer-read-only` is ignored.

Comment: Ah OK, I totally missed that call to `command-error-default-function`.

Comment: Thanks! Could one also separate minibuffer and echo area this way, or would it require a change to the C code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063410/is-it-possible-to-separate-minibuffer-and-echo-area-in-emacs

Comment: Sweet, I've been looking for an easy way to get rid of that "Text is read-only" garbage only in the minibuffer and this does the trick.

Comment: @mcb: As far as I know it is not possible to separate the echo area and mini-buffer. I believe that [the answer by `phils` that you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067948) is correct, i.e. we would need new C code for this.

Answer (score 3):

### Source of the 'buffer read-only' error

I believe that the source of that error: `Buffer is read-only: <#BUFFER-NAME>` is in the C source code.

So the solution to this would be to tweak the source code and build emacs locally by commenting out [this specific line](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/buffer.c?a=a2981c90f661e8fa0356ee5bfe00f8565d721de8#n2156).

For reference, here is that code snippet that throws that error:

```c
if (!NILP (BVAR (current_buffer, read_only))
    && NILP (Vinhibit_read_only)
    && NILP (Fget_text_property (pos, Qinhibit_read_only, Qnil)))
  xsignal1 (Qbuffer_read_only, Fcurrent_buffer ());
return Qnil;
```

.. and commenting out that `xsignal` line should do the trick.

---

### Suggested Approach

There is a much easier way to avert this annoyance for the duration you are working in a read-only buffer .. you can temporarily NOT make it read-only.

- Doing `M-x read-only-mode` (bound by default to `C-x C-q`) toggles *any* buffer between read-only mode and editable mode.

So if you are getting a lot of these errors, simply make the buffer temporarily editable by hitting `C-x C-q`.

---

*A note of warning: Doing the C source hack could be a major source of confusion in future. So I wouldn't do it.*

Comment: As far as I can tell `(defun barf-if-buffer-read-only () nil)` has the same effect as commenting out the `xsignal1` call and re-building Emacs. :-)

Comment: @Constantine TIL that we can override C functions in elisp. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding modifying things using elisp: this reminds me of this old question about `nil`: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2935/how-can-i-bring-back-nil